# vsftpd not allowing local users to connect

Tags: linux, ftp

I have CentOS running **vsftpd** but I am unable to connect using loccl users (`local_enable=YES`). If I set `anonymous_enable=YES` then it works just fine, but when I enter my user name and password (I don't want to allow anonymous connections) then all I see is 'Cannot display the webpage' error.

I'm no Linux expert, but as far as I can tell the username/password combination that I am using is fine and the user is allowed by **vsftpd**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the browser or the FTP client you are using is not sending the username/password to the FTP server.

If you using a browser-like URL, try to use one of these forms:

```
ftp://user@ftpserver/url-path
ftp://user:password@ftpserver/url-path
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both of those take me to the same 'Cannot display the webpage' error. I've tried in an FTP client now as well, and logging in as 'root' yeilds the error 'Access denied'. I have `userlist_enabled=YES` in **vsftpd.conf** and 'root' is listed in `/etc/vsftpd/user_list`. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Ok, so I've figured out to change to `userlist_enabled=NO`, so the username and password is being accepted, but now I'm getting the error **500 OOPS: Cannot change directory: {directory from chroot_list}**. That directory is set to 777, so everyone should be able to change it.

Comment: Setting directory mode to 777 may not be enough if its parent can not be accessed.

Comment: Got it - there was an erronious 's' at the end of one of the files. All connected to FTP now, just a couple of small issues that I can hopefully fix! Thanks for your advice.